# C# login with website verification

Tags: c#, php, mysql, database-connection

Hi I'm making a program where you must sign in to use the program. On our website you will create a user, that information is put into a db. However our host provider has disabled extern connection to the db, so it's only possible to access the database through php.

So here's the question.
What's is the easiest way to make this login system (in the c# program)?

- Is it via a REST interface (php), then I should be able to make a connection.
- Send a string with the hashed user information, that the website then checks with the hashed data in the database. The website then returns with a yes or no.
- A third way?

What do you guys think is the best way?

Comment: You can use REST/Soap/RPC or what ever. As long as you make sure your code is secure, it doesn't matter. Choose what you think is easiest for you and just try it. Start with the actual authentication logic, then you can try different ways of exposing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you handle the login through a php document, then you could open it using a  php-capable webbrowser-control, therefore executing the php and logging in the user. By the way, pay attention not to show the webbrowser to the user unless you are certain your application is secure enough and does not show sensitive information.

Comment: Why would you go through a web browser instead of making http requests directly to the endpoints?